# How to conditionally deserialize to a POJO field using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

How can I conditionally deserialize a JSON string to a POJO field?

I receive a JSON string like so:

```
{
 "status": "we stuck",
 "data" : "someData"
}
```

but "someData" can be just a string "under the bridge" or can be something like "['bridge 5', 'Mandela bridge']" or "[{'incident 1' : '['bridge 1', 'bridge 2]'},{'incident 2' : ['bridge 99', 'what ever else']}]"

I want to return the json string AS IS if "data" is an array then I will map to a different Type that deals with the array

I have a java class:

```
class Response {
  String status;
  String data;
}
```

the other Type will have data as

```
ArrayList<SomeOtherType> data;
```

This is what i have so far

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Response rspns = mapper.readValue(<theJSONStrHere>, Response.class);
```

this fails when data is an array, giving me the message

> can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a custom deserializer as aussie said or you can just modify your working solution.

```
class Response {
  String status;
  String data;
}

class Other {
  String status;    
  ArrayList<SomeOtherType> data;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Other rspns = mapper.readValue(<theJSONStrHere>, Other.class);
```

This will parse the JSON String to the `Other` class with the ArrayList.
Now it's your turn to implement the decision of then to use

```
Other rspns = mapper.readValue(<theJSONStrHere>, Other.class);
```

or when to use

```
Responserspns = mapper.readValue(<theJSONStrHere>, Response.class);
```

**Note:** The above is a quick and dirty solution. It works like that but I would highly recommend to use a custom deserializer, which handles the logic of what it is and what to return. 
Also keep in mind that for this to work the best you might consider building the POJO structure to multiple classes which extend a base class and then work generic.

**example:**

```
class response {
  String status;
}

class simpleResponse extends response {
  String data;
}

class listResponse extends response {
  ArrayList<Type> data;
}

class MyDeserializer extends JSONDeserializer<E extends response> {
   public E deserialize...) {

   }
}
```

To get an actual working example read about [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki)

Comment: does this mean MyDeserializer will automatically pick which Response subclass to return?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but the logic which one it returns has to be implemented by you in the deserializer. So you have to build the logic no matter what but the deserializer will have the advantage to have this logic in one place. Which means you can use this everywhere and anytime you want.
The advantage of this hierachy means you can put the base class `response` with everything you need and let it be overwritten by the subclasses. For Example a function `getData()` in `response` which returns an Object. but the subclasses Overwrite this method with their specific type.

Comment: Since you deserializer will return a generic ( for example `E` ) you will get `E` in your code were you retrieve the json which then can be cast to the base class `response` or you can define which exact subclass it is with reflection like `if(result instanceof simpleResponse) { simpleRespone casted = (simpleRespone) result; }`. If you don't know about generics or never did anything with those types of variables/objects, I would recommend to read about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Dont make it complicated think simple..

There are two ways

**First**  taking List os string/(or any other type)

```
private List<String> tags;
```

**Second**  taking List of class (if you need more than one parameters)

```
List<PageLink> pagelinks;
```

**See below case example......**

```
public class PagesJson {
    private String ln;
    private int pageno;
    private List<String> tags;
    private List<PageLink> pagelinks;
    private String error;
}

public class PageLink {
    private String title= null;
    private String url;
}
```

Now json of **PagesJson** class as below

{"ln":en,"count":100,"viewcount":23,"pageno":17,"tags":["Ensuring safe motherhood","pregnancy health in women","Abortion"],"pagelinks":[{"title":"Abortion","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/health/women-health"},{"title":"Acts and Rules","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/social-welfare/scheduled-tribes-welfare/acts-and-rules"},{"title":"Acts and Rules ","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/social-welfare/unorganised-sector-1/acts-and-rules"}],"error":"Parameter Validation Error"}

```
{"ln":en,"count":100,"viewcount":23,"pageno":17,"tags":["Ensuring safe motherhood","pregnancy health in women","Abortion"],"pagelinks":[{"title":"Abortion","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/health/women-health"},{"title":"Acts and Rules","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/social-welfare/scheduled-tribes-welfare/acts-and-rules"},{"title":"Acts and Rules ","url":"http://vikaspedia.in/social-welfare/unorganised-sector-1/acts-and-rules"}],"error":"Parameter Validation Error"}
```

For Mapping json to class use **jackson** library as below.....

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
....
.....
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

PagesJson pj = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), PagesJson.class);
```

Comment: There is no actual example how you retrieve the values. Most important part missing

Comment: thanks for reminding .... @Nico    i have updated how to map json to class... 

For Mapping json to class use jackson library

Comment: Thanks, Piyush - but in a case similar to mine. let's say tags CAN also come as "the are no tags" .. will the tags in PagesJson be a list with just one element "the are no tags" or fail to deserialize? I have no control of the json string I receive

Comment: Yes tags will accept one string as list with one element and ......if no tags is json...list will be null or blank........you just need to create ObjectMapper object with .... Deserialization Feature.FAIL_0N_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Deserializer on a Method OR a Class using below :

```
extends JsonDeserializer
```

then

```
@Override
public ReturnObject deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonToken token = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if(JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(token)){
        //TODO your JSON Array code handling
        }else{
        //TO DO you JSON Object Handling
        }
}
```