# Jackson conditional mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

So I am receiving a JSON string and trying to map to a POJO that is nested a few degrees. One of the object is a List and contains a list of events (Event class). I want to ONLY map the Event and add it to the list if a certain field in the Event class is equal to "x". The input String is massive and I'm only grabbing a handful of attributes. Then once it is mapped, if I print it out as a String I get let's say...

```
{
    "status":"completed",
    "_embedded":{
        "events":[
             {
                 "type":"started"
             },
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             },
             {
                 "type":"started"
             },
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             },
             {
                 "type":"started"
             },
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             }
         ]
     }
}
```

I now want a way to make the mapping conditional so that when I map to a POJO and then print it out as a String I would get...

```
{
    "status":"completed",
    "_embedded":{
        "events":[
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             },
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             },
             {
                 "type":"completed"
             }
         ]
     }
}
```

So only if the "type" is "completed" I would keep those event objects in the array, discard the rest.

Comment: You can create a custom deserializer. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042854/how-to-conditionally-deserialize-to-a-pojo-field-using-jackson

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Gson lib that supports generics and nested beans also.

example `Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);`

Comment: I am familiar with this library as well. What you are suggesting is going to achieve what I already am achieving which is mapping.

Comment: Let say you have mapped object then simply use filter 
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

List<Event> completedEvent = events.stream().filter( e-> e.isComplete) .collect(Collectors.toList());